# Partition reassignment of Kafka using Helm charts

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, kubernetes-helm

I wish to reassign partitions in Kafka on scale in/scale out of nodes deployed on Kubernetes using helm charts.

I have written a python script which can perform the necessary actions. However, I wish to do the same using Helm charts itself without having to involve any additional scripts.

I was checking out the Helm charts for Kafka in the [Helm Github repo](https://github.com/helm/charts).

I came across the [configmap-config](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/incubator/kafka/templates/configmap-config.yaml) file inside their templates. I am very new to Helm. Hence, having difficulty in interpreting the YAML file.

Line numbers 39 and 40 have the following commands which is precisely what I am executing using my python scripts.

```
kafka-reassign-partitions --zookeeper {{ $zk }} --reassignment-json-file {{ $topic.name }}-increase-replication-factor.json --execute
kafka-reassign-partitions --zookeeper {{ $zk }} --reassignment-json-file {{ $topic.name }}-increase-replication-factor.json --verify
```

Can you please explain how can these lines be triggered using Helm charts itself without having to run any script.

Answer (score 0):

The token `$` indicates a variable. So, `{{ $zk }}` means that this variable were defined before, in this case at [line 2](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/incubator/kafka/templates/configmap-config.yaml#L2). And this info is defined at section [zookeeper](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/21abd3a8eca0b555688e3c218f53a771b0bf2f7f/incubator/kafka/values.yaml#L367) at line [392](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/21abd3a8eca0b555688e3c218f53a771b0bf2f7f/incubator/kafka/values.yaml#L392) from **values.yaml** file.

The same thing for `{{ topic.name }}`. You should define this info in **values.yaml** too.

Then, you can install using Helm.

Comment: I understand that but can we execute those commands from the helm scripts?

Comment: You can run the helm install command like`helm install /path/for/charts/ -f /path/for/values.yaml --name pfweb-sbx` then helm does the magic.

Comment: Thank you. However I know how to run helm charts, but the real deal is running the mentioned Kafka specific commands (mentioned in the question) from inside the helm charts. Help on those grounds would be appreciated.